# I need to limit list entries to no more than 1 every 30 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint list for quality checks.  Our last corp. audit failed us on to many entries for a specific time frame (5 entries in 2 minutes).

Is there coding or OOB solution to limit entries to 1 every 30 minutes?

Comment: entries for what? list? please edit your question and add more details to avoid closing the question and to help u faster

Answer (score 1):

Add a **calculated column** called UserTimeCheck that is required and unique and uses a time formula.

For example: `=TEXT(NOW(),"mmddyyyyhh")&ROUNDUP(MINUTE(NOW())/30,0)`

So you might get away with doing a entry at 1:29 and 1:31, but you couldn't do a bunch of entries in a row.

Example makes sure no entries overlap - add calculations if you want to make it so no user or department makes entries within 30 minutes. If you use this method, it is important to note that it is not full-proof. If a user adds the column to a personal view then it could be cleared and recalculated, or they could try to put other data in there using the datasheet view etc. However, most of those leave auditable logs, so it enables you to mitigate using HR.